# Using clustered than non-clustered index with columns that include date and nvarchar(50)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called 'GameTransactions'. It is critical for the table to work well in terms of performance (The table will have millions of records when the site is going to be operational). I thought to index it. The columns that I used for the columns are:

```
UserID [int],
TransactionID [nvarchar(50)]
ProviderID [int]
TransactionTimeStamp [datetime]
```

Some context on how I use the table.

At the begining of the SQL operation I check if the transaction ID exists for the same user.

```
   SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM GameTransactions WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
    UserID=@UserID AND
    TransactionID=@TransactionID 
    AND ProviderID=@ProviderID 
    AND TransactionTimeStamp>DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETUTCDATE())
```

If the request doesnt already exist in the database, I insert it.

I chose to use the following index

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_GameTransactions_UserID_TransactionID_ProviderID_TransactionTimeStamp
ON dbo.GameTransactions (UserID,TransactionID,ProviderID,TransactionTimeStamp);
```

I read in this article:

> https://sqlstudies.com/2014/12/01/using-a-date-or-int-column-as-the-clustered-index/

That it is possible to achieve good performance with datetime being a column in a clustered index. I dont care about disk space that the clustered index is going to take, I am more concerned about speed performance.

I also thought about an alternative solution,

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_GameTransactions_UserID_TransactionID_ProviderID_TransactionTimeStamp
 ON dbo.GameTransactions (UserID, Month, Year,ProviderID)
 INCLUDE (TransactionID);
```

I could add 2 additional columns - Month and year. And work with ints instead of date. Keep in mind that the 'TransactionID' field has to be an nvarchar(50). There is no way to work around it.

I have an additional Id column which is auto-incrementing. Would such a solution work?

```
  CONSTRAINT PK_GameTransactions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
      UserID
    , TransactionID
    , ProviderID
    , TransactionTimeStamp
, Id
)
```

Comment: What would all those non-clustered indexes give me? other than more scan times and storage space?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT` to conditionally insert the row. This will be more efficient since a count is not needed. Make sure the index is unique to ensure duplicates are not possible.

Use `>=` instead of `>` for the timestamp criteria so that 2 sessions with the same timestamp don't both insert the same row, although one would err if a unique index or constraint exists.

Furthermore, consider removing `NOLOCK` to ensure concurrent sessions don't insert rows for the same UserID/TransactionID/ProviderID withing the TransactionTimeStamp date range. I suggest `SERIALIZABLE` for this purpose. Example DDL below with the query encapsulated in a stored procedure below, leveraging the primary key index for both performance and data integrity.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.GameTransactions(
      UserID int
    , TransactionID nvarchar(50)
    , ProviderID int
    , TransactionTimeStamp datetime
    CONSTRAINT PK_GameTransactions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
          UserID
        , TransactionID
        , ProviderID
        , TransactionTimeStamp
    )
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertGameTransactions
      @UserID int
    , @TransactionID nvarchar(50)
    , @ProviderID int
AS
DECLARE @TransactionTimeStamp datetime = GETUTCDATE();
INSERT INTO dbo.GameTransactions (
      UserID
    , TransactionID 
    , ProviderID 
    , TransactionTimeStamp
)
SELECT
      @UserID
    , @TransactionID 
    , @ProviderID 
    , @TransactionTimeStamp
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.GameTransactions WITH(SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE 
        UserID=@UserID AND
        TransactionID=@TransactionID 
        AND ProviderID=@ProviderID 
        AND TransactionTimeStamp >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@TransactionTimeStamp)
    );
GO
```

Comment: I can see that you used the columns as primary key. That seems to be a good solution. The only problem with that safety check, is that it cant be it comes at the end of my stored procedure (which is full of other sql statements in-between). Second, problem is that I have an auto-incrementing primary key already that I use. Can I combine them all together? just add the Id into the clustered key. Is it possible to configure it like that with the Id being able to auto-increment after each insert.

Comment: I don't see the `Id` column referenced in you question. How is it used in queries? There are a number of options to mix and match various index types and keys but it depends on the workload mix. My answer is focused only on the conditional insert query gleaned from your question.

Comment: I have an auto-incrementing Id column. I need that column to be the primary key too. see the update to my question.

Comment: The auto-increment `Id` column provides no value as part of the index key in this case. Why does it exist if not referenced anywhere?

Comment: It exists because I need it as an output to an external entity. I need to provide a transaction ID of my own.

Comment: If you don't specify the `Id` column in query JOIN or WHERE clause predicates, there is no need to add an index on the column for performance. But you should ensure the value is unique by adding a unique constraint, which will create a unique index as a side-effect that is non-clustered by default.

Answer (score 1):

First, a clustered index has no benefit for your comparison.

Second, I strongly agree with Dan that you should be using `EXISTS` rather than `SELECT COUNT(*)` if you care about performance.

Third, you are taking the *wrong* message from the blog.  The issue with clustered indexes is that the data is stored in-order on the data pages.  When you have a clustered index, you can have a big performance bottleneck when you have to insert rows "between" other rows.

For this reason, the normal advice is to use an `identity` column as the clustered index key (which is the default, by the way).  This is good advice, but there are other circumstances as well.  For instance, `newsequentialid()` is a function that generates GUIDs that are suitable for a clustered index, because they are (almost always) increasing.

In your case, the first column in the index is *not* a date/time.  So you are probably going to have fragmentation problems galore in using such a clustered index.  For what you want to do, there is no reason to order the data on the data pages.  Just use  a regular index with all the columns you need as keys.

Comment: 'you can have a big performance bottleneck when you have to insert rows "between" other rows.' - I never need to insert rows between other rows. '. Just use a regular index with all the columns you need as keys.'- So are you saying that I should use the columns as a primary key instead of using clustered index. Why wouldnt creating an clustered or nonclustered for a few columns in the where clause speed up performance, and why my solution is wrong and I should stick to only one auto-incrementing primary key?